# Is this epsilon-delta proof that $\sin(x)$ is continuous circular?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

> Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}\sin x=\sin a$, where $a$ is any real number.

Solution 13 here:

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preclimsoldirectory/PrecLimSol.html#SOLUTION13

claims to prove that $\sin(x)$ is continous, in other words: for every real $a$, $\lim_{x\to a}\sin(x)=\sin(a)$. The solution uses the Mean Value Theorem, which only works if the function in question is differentiable on some interval; in particular the function must be continous on some interval. So the solution is assuming that $\sin(x)$ is continous in order to prove that it is continous.

Is this solution bogus or am I missing something?

Note: I am not asking you to provide a correct proof. I already know of a correct proof (which does not use MVT).

Comment: It would be good if you reproduced the relevant portion of the link here, given that links often die.

Comment: It does look weird.

Comment: You might want to send a message to the author of the website about this problem (and the following one); I think he would appreciate it.

Comment: I've emailed the author.

Comment: Did your email inform the author of this MSE question?   It would be interesting to see his comments on the question and answers.

Comment: Well the author didn't respond to my email yet.

Comment: This is a good question, which has generated extensive discussion.  I agree with Michael Hardy, ajotatxe, David K, and Ian that the proof as written is a circular argument (even if that makes me a "literalist").  I think that ASCII Advocate is making a valid point, though; unlike many circular proofs, this argument provides useful information (as Dorebell points out), and it can be reworded slightly to become a useful exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. That "proof" is totally wrong for the reason that you said. The same thing could be done with *any* function.

Comment: Doesn't it, however, depend on which definition of continuity (of many equivalent) you are using? The problem does not explicitly ask to prove that $\sin x$ is continuous.

Comment: If this course has proven the mean value theorem, and that $\sin x$ is continuous for some definition of continuity, but not that their definition of continuity is equivalent to the $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$ definition, then I'm not certain I would call it circular logic.

Comment: On the same web site, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ is given as one of the conditions of continuity: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/continuitydirectory/. So I think the "proof" is guilty as charged.

Comment: It's not true that the same thing could be done with any function, if that means the mean value theorem could be used.  The mean value theorem depends on differentiability. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's true if you given for granted that is differentiable. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

He's trying to prove $f(x)=\sin x$ is continuous, and within the proof he actually says "since $f$ is continuous" and draws conclusions from that and uses them in the proof.

That's as crystal-clear a case of circular reasoning as I can imagine.

Answer (score -4):

The answers you got are excessively literal.  They are at best technically correct on their own terms, and will gather some votes since it is fun to validate clever observation of errors in class material.  But it is misleading to describe the solution as circular.

By "prove" the author of the web page means "find an explicit function $D(x)$ so that setting $\delta = D(\epsilon)$ satisfies the epsilon-based definition of continuity or limit".   That is why the web page is titled
*SOLUTIONS TO LIMITS OF FUNCTIONS USING THE PRECISE DEFINITION OF LIMIT*.
The purpose of the page is to illustrate the technique of using the mean-value theorem to obtain epsilon-delta estimates.  It is not circular, in applying that technique, to assume a function is continuous and differentiable, in order to prove concrete estimates demonstrating continuity at some given point.

You can of course get a joke proof by reciting the epsilon-delta definition of continuity and saying "whatever $\delta$ makes the continuity assumption true!".  But that is not an estimate that can be computed on its own without the continuity assumptions.  If you ask for such computability as part of what is to be proved, then there is no circularity.

To very specifically answer the criticism,

> So the solution is assuming that $\sin (x)$ is continuous in order to prove that it is continuous.

No.  The solution is assuming that $f(x)=\sin x$ is continuous, differentiable, and with a known formula for its derivative; in order to prove that $|f'(x)|$ is bounded (which is the key to getting a computable bound on $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$, which is what the page means by "using the precise definition of limit").  There are examples of differentiable functions with unbounded derivatives on a finite closed interval. The existence of the examples means that assuming continuous etc is not enough to get the intended conclusion.

At most there is a criticism that "using the precise definition of limit" is defined only from the context of a class, book, or web page.  But it always implies computability (as in computability theory) and that can be taken as a very broad and sufficient definition for discussions like this one that parse things down to very fine details.

Comment: "It is not circular, in applying that technique, to assume a function is continuous and differentiable, in order to prove concrete estimates demonstrating continuity at some given point." - I don't see how it is not circular but are you trying to say that it is a good excercise even if it not a proper proof?

Comment: I agree. Of course, this argument is not a valid proof that the sine function is continuous. But let's assume you've shown it's differentiable already using a geometric argument or by defining it to be its power series or something (it's generally hard to avoid being circular with trig functions, so *defining* them to be equal to their power series, which are clearly smooth, is one way out). You may know abstractly that the function is continuous, but you don't know what relationship exists between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. This explicit information is useful and that's what this proof finds.

Comment: You are right that one might use the mean value theorem in the process of trying to find the value of $\delta$, but you still need to prove by some other method, not relying on the statement to be proved, that that value of $\delta$ will work.  The page doesn't do that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The proof does not "rely on the statement to be proved" ( @MichaelHardy ).  What is to be proved is essentially a bound on $|f'(x)|$.  The proof relies on the facts that $f(x)$ is continuous, differentiable, and with a known formula for the derivative.  None of those facts individually or in combination implies any bound on the derivative, which means that there is nothing circular in assuming them for the proof.  The claim of circularity is based on an extremely literal reading of the problem, but this question is about the  *solution*, and all I have written then applies.

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate : I took the thing to be proved to be the statement that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\sin x = \sin a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, it is specifically stated that they are not looking for any old proof of this fact but a proof using the "precise definition of limit".  As is patently clear from the webpage, that means "sufficient $\delta$ that is a computable function of $\epsilon$".  Quoting the definition of continuity for $\sin x$ does not provide any computable bound.

Comment: The literalists are voting again, as predicted in my opening sentence.   I have added to the answer some material relevant to the subsequent discussion.  (Paging @MichaelHardy ... )

Comment: As written, it is circular. However, you are right that there is some merit in this approach. Knowing in advance that $f$ is actually going to turn out to be differentiable, we can do a quick "mean value theorem calculation" in order to come up with the appropriate choice of $\delta$. Specifically we find that $|\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)|\leq|h|$, so that it will work out for us to take $\delta=\varepsilon$. But that's just scratch work: once we've convinced ourselves that $\delta=\varepsilon$ will work, we have to *prove* that, and for that we cannot use anything that would imply continuity for free.

Comment: Though in this case it actually doesn't help much, at least if you're starting from trigonometry: it's easier to write $|\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)| \leq |\cos(h)-1| + |\sin(h)|$, and then use that, which requires a slightly smaller $\delta$ than the optimal one.

Comment: As written, neither the original problem statement ("prove [lim sin(x) = sin(a)] using the precise definition of limit") nor the solution are circular, since the target of both is to prove specific bounds sufficient to imply continuity.  This is a stronger requirement than continuity which also raises the threshold for what would be circular reasoning.   To paraphrase @Ian 's comment, we "cannot use anything that would imply [precise epsilon-delta bounds] for free", but the solution doesn't do that.  Certainly assuming continuity and differentiability doesn't do that.

Comment: The way the author intended to prove the desired statement (and all of the other examples in the link) was by furnishing explicit bounds, but at the end of the day, it is clearly labeled that the statement "$\lim_{x \to a} \sin(x) = \sin(a)$", not the statement "$(\forall \varepsilon > 0,a \in \mathbb{R}) \: |x-a|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |\sin(x)-\sin(a)|<\varepsilon$", is that which is to be proven. The link provides a valid proof of the latter *given* the fact that $\sin$ is continuously differentiable with derivative equal to $\cos$, and does not provide a valid proof of the former at all.

Comment: Sorry, I made a minor error in formulating the latter statement, it should say $(\forall \varepsilon > 0,x \in \mathbb{R},a \in \mathbb{R}) \: |x-a|<\varepsilon \Rightarrow |\sin(x)-\sin(a)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou, do the edit and comments discussion here answer your comment-question? It seems to me that the answer is ultimately that the supposed circularity arises from omitting the words "using the precise definition of limit" in the excerpted problem posted here. They did appear at the source of the problem and solution, https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preciselimdirectory/PreciseLimit.html .  Given those words and an understanding of what they require of the proof (a computable $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$) it is not circular to assume $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: @Ian, see preceding.  At the end of the day we have an incompletely quoted problem inferred from the list of the solutions.  The actual problem list had sufficient context to make clear that a computable $\delta$ is required as part of what is to be proved ("precise definition of limit" .... "appropriate value for $\delta$ can be easily determined [as function of $\varepsilon$]").   This cuts the logical circle people have been claiming exists in the solution with MVT.   Making a noncircular solution look circular by taking it out of context is not the same as really being circular.

Comment: It's not out of context. Read the very first sentence in that section of the link. That sets the context very straightforwardly.

Comment: I just quoted words that are part of the missing context, that appear directly above the list of problems, and are sufficient to kill the (claimed) circularity.  Those words do not appear in this here question at Stackexchange, about circularity. Given that we are talking about whether the solution is circular or not, that would seem to be a very clear case of out of context quotation.  I don't understand what part of what link you are suggesting would erase that discrepancy and make the problem excerpt posted here "not out of context".  @Ian

Comment: "Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} \sin(x) = \sin(a)$" is the very first sentence in solution 13 in the link in the original question. The proof given there assumes $\sin$ is continuous, which immediately implies this result with no calculation whatsoever. You are right that assuming $\sin$ is continuous does not furnish its modulus of continuity; but this is the same distinction that I made earlier. The proof given *is* a valid proof that $\omega(\varepsilon)=\varepsilon$ is a modulus of continuity for $\sin$.

Comment: @Ian, it is completely standard to precede a list of such exercises (on computing moduli of continuity for particular functions) by exactly the words like "precise definition of limit" that indicate the problem is to find a modulus of continuity.   This list is targeted at students of "Beginning Differential Calculus" ( https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/ProblemsList.html ) so that more specific descriptions like *modulus of continuity* and *computable upper bound* are avoided.   Bounds on the modulus via MVT are a staple exercise in calculus classes and modulus is what is meant here.

Comment: (And you are referring to the list of *solutions* in the question, whereas I provided, a few comments up, a list of the *problems* that they solve.  The problems and text on the problem page are the missing context.  It is quite clear that every problem there is a request for a modulus of continuity, not the bare fact of continuity.)  @Ian

Comment: @ASCIIAdvocate : You say one is to find "sufficient $\delta$ that is a computable function of $\varepsilon$", but is it not also necessary to _prove_ that the $\delta$ you've found is sufficient? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, yes.  The exercise is to prove that some concrete  $\delta$ is a modulus of continuity, by assuming continuity and differentiability, and applying the mean value theorem to bound the derivative.   Simple examples with oscillatory functions show that the continuity and differentiability assumptions do not imply a bound for the derivative.  So the proof does not reduce to a circular "continuous implies continuous" as some are representing it here, but does say "specific facts about this particular function, plus enough regularity to apply MVT, imply specific bounds on $f'(x)$".